How would I configure Kapacitor to send alert messages to a DingTalk group
DingTalk is an intelligent working platform created by Alibaba Group to support tens of millions of enterprises to achieve higher working efficiency with the new digitalized working method.
I am running a Kapacitor trying to monitor any changes in InfluxDB cluster so to send alerts to my local DingTalk group.
I know I could write a similar handler and here is the webhook of the DingTalk.
Any best practice or guideline to integrate these two tools?
